# AsymptoticDSolveValue

Tags: differential-equations, asymptotics

this is the first time ever i am posting a problem on ANY forum as i am desperate to find asymptotic approximation to this problem with any boundary or initial condition
please see if you can help
Although it appears to be regular but i believe its singular

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

ode = 3*F*ϵ*W[T]*W''[T]*(c1)*(c2^2) - 9*F*W[T]^2*(c1)*(c2^2) + 
   3*W[T]^2*(F*(c2^2)*β - (c1^2))*W'[T] + 
   W[T]^4 (((T^3 - 3*T) β + 3*T + 3 c)*W[T] + 3*(c1) (T^2 + β - 1)) == 0

ic = {W[0] == 1, W[1] == 2}

sol = AsymptoticDSolveValue[{ode, ic}, W[T], T, {ϵ, 0, 1}];
```

Answer (score -1):

With some bracket balancing , the input seems to be busy forever. With fixing real values for the constants, the input is returned  unevaluted  after 3 min.

```
TimeConstraint[With[{c = 5, c1 = 1, c2 = \[Pi], \[Beta] = 3, F = 7},
     AsymptoticDSolveValue[{
       3*F*\[CurlyEpsilon]*W[T]*W''[T]*(c1)*(c2^2) -
         9*F*W[T]^2*(c1)*(c2^2) +
         3*W[T]^2*(F*(c2^2)*\[Beta] - (c1^2))*W'[T] + 
         W[T]^4 (((T^3 - 3*T) \[Beta] + 3*T + 3 c)*W[T] +
            3*(c1) (T^2 + \[Beta] - 1))
               == 0,
       W[0] == 1,
       W[1] == 2
       }, W[T], T, \[CurlyEpsilon] -> 0]],200]
```

Comment: Thanks Ronald F